# Reading csv rows into multiple arrays

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 2 rows of data, like this:

```
a1, b1, c1, d1
a2, b2, c2, d2
```

I want to take row 1 and append that to an array, and append row 2 to a seperate array like so:

```py
row1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"]
row2 = ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"]
```

My code for writing the data to the csv file is this:

```py
import csv
with open("file.csv", "w") as csvFile:
            csvFileReader = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=";")
            csvFileReader.writerows([[", ".join(arrValues1)],
                                     [", ".join(arrValues2)]])
csvFile.close()
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried with `csv.reader()` ?

Comment: yes, but my issue is separating each row from each other, and appending each item as a seperate value, my code: `fileFileRead = csv.reader(File, delimiter=",")`

Comment: use `next` twice on `csv.reader` object

Comment: `csvFileReader = csv.writer`... confusing.

Comment: `fileFileRead ` This one already done your job. It stores each row as a list of elements. Do you want to assign row number for each row?

Comment: thank you, i'll try that and fix the variable names

Answer (score 0):

To read your data, use `next` twice on a `csv.reader` object. `next` iterates on the writer manually, issuing one row each time unless reader is exhausted.

```
import csv
with open("file.csv", "r", newline="") as csvFile:
      reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=",")
      arrValues1 = next(reader)
      arrValues2 = next(reader)
```

BTW to write your array in the first place, you should use `csv.writer` properly, no need to `str.join`:

```
import csv
with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as csvFile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=",")
      writer.writerows([arrValues1,arrValues2])
```